# Normalize unicode character in sql query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, unicode

Unicode characters can be encoded in different ways, canonical equivalence and compatibility. We can normalize them to get the same character as it is important for exact string match. My sample code base

```
$search = Normalizer::normalize($request->get('search'), Normalizer::FORM_C);
```

I am normalizing the request search keyword in NFC (Canonical Decomposition followed by Canonical Composition). And then I used that normalized string to search in database.

```
$products = Product::where('title', "LIKE", "%" . $search . "%")->get();
```

this line generates a sql query

```
select * from `products` where `title` LIKE %রায়হান% and `products`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Here `রায়হান` is my search string. I get two different encoding for the character `য়`. One is for `য়` itself that is `%E0%A7%9F` and one is `%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%BC` that is `য` + `়`
My database values may have both the encoding as I didn't normalize them before saving. So when searching I get the values only those matches the normalized search key. Even if I don't normalize the search key, getting only matching encoded values.

Now I know I can normalize the string before saving and then search with the normalized string. But I already have some values that is not normalized. So is there any way to normalize the string when querying the database? Something like

```
select * from `products` where NormalizedNFC(`title`) LIKE %my_normalized_value_in_php% and `products`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but MySQL's *collation* may be able to compensate for this. What's your collation set to?

Comment: collation is `utf_unicode_ci`.

Comment: OK, that's probably the best choice; if it can't do it, then it just can't.

Comment: so there's no way to normalize when querying?

Comment: I didn't say that. I just wanted to make sure collations weren't the easy solution.

Comment: get the point. collation is not helping me here. and ironically not getting any similar issue anywhere.